# Get array from .begin() and .end() iterators

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, openacc

I'm trying to get the array "inside" an `std::vector`.

I don't know C++ that well so basically I'm looking for a snippet to get the array (which is the pointer to the first element, iirc) and the size. I need this, because I want to transfer the content of the array to an accelerator device via *OpenACC*.

All I get from the function I'm supposed to manipulate, are **two RA-Iterators for the beginning and the end of the data**.

I know that not all of those have to be contiguous but the code I'll produce will be purely academical, so that should not be an issue for now.

Comment: You mean `vector.data()` ?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't have the vector object in my context. I only get the results of vector.begin() and vector.end().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::vector` is guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, so that shouldn't be an issue. You can get the address of (read: pointer to) the first element with

```
&*a.begin()
```

or more easily with

```
&a.first()
```

To get the size from `.begin()` and `.end()`, use

```
a.end() - a.begin()
```

Comment: I've downvoted your answer. Can you edit your answer so I can up-vote it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the entire vector, `vector.data()` is your friend.

If you need only a part of it:

```
std::vector<X>::iterator it1 = ... , it2 = ...;
X* item = &(*it1);
int elements = it2 - it1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray[myvector.end() - myvector.begin()]
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin(), int i = 0; it!=myvector.end(); ++it, ++i)
        myArray[i] = myvector[i]// or whatever you want
```

This is how you use the iterators; make sure to use a loop because you have the beginning condition and the end condition.

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP is asking for a way to retrieve the underlying data from two iterators and you are simply showing how to loop over a container using iterators.

Comment: This copies the data out of the vector into the array, which would work as well, but I need to work in-place so that isn't an option for me. Your answer might work for others though.

Comment: @ChristopherGuckes I now realize what you wanted, which is the currently accepted answer. Anyways, thanks for the question.